# Select Records From Table If Table Exists - In Single Statement

Tags: mysql

I am getting a 1064 error with the following statement - note: both clauses of the statement work OK individually. I understood that should any records be produced from the first clause then the second would be actioned? I don't want to use a stored procedure and techniques using a SET @val also seem to fail. Any ideas anyone please?

```
SELECT TABLE_NAME FROM information_schema.TABLES WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'ft_form_103'  WHERE EXISTS  (SELECT * FROM 'ft_form_103');
```

Answer (score 0):

I could not understand your what you actually wanted, but looking at your script their is a syntax error. I have corrected the syntax and below sql will work. Hope this is what you were looking for.

SQL:
SELECT IFNULL((SELECT TABLE_NAME FROM information_schema.TABLES 
WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'ft_form_103'),'Table not found') AS table_name;;

Comment: Hi @user3454116... I need to run SELECT statements on 'random' table names. These tables are user specified and, where a given table does not exist, I do not want the query to ERROR. I can't trap this in the function code and I can't use stored procedures. I tried your suggested code but it failed with #1109 - Unknown table 'ft_form_103' in information_schema. If I remove AND EXISTS statement , the code works OK

Comment: what do you want the query to do, if the table doesn't exist?

Comment: Hi @user3454116... Thanks for the reply and good question!. Actually once I had proved the query I was going to change it to a NOT EXISTS statement whereby if the user selected a non-existent table I would create a 'dummy' return e.g. NOT EXISTS (SELECT 'Invalid Selection'  etc etc). More fully, I have two input boxes; the input from the first is used to build the above query, the records from which are then used to populate the second (dropdown) box. I am trying to avoid the situation where, if a user specifies an invalid table, the whole thing ERRORS out.

Comment: Hi,
I think i got your requirement, so i have created a query and updated in the answer section to search for your table in the parameter and if the table is not present it will give result as 'table not found' and if the table is found it would return the name of the table.

Comment: Hi @user3454116... That's really close but if the table does exist I would like to return the records from it...  Your suggestion made me think about a CASE Statement... so........  SELECT CASE (SELECT TABLE_NAME FROM information_schema.TABLES WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'ft_form_103') WHEN NULL 'Table Not Found' ELSE (SELECT name FROM ft_form_103) END AS MyRecords   but this fails with a 2014 error commands out of sync....